# Netbeans - Keeps crashing after running for awhile due to "run.xml:53: Java returned: 2"

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

After running my code for awhile in Netbeans, the program will, without fail, crash and display this message:

> C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 2
>
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 50 minutes 43 seconds)

Outside of this message, no errors are ever mentioned.
While I am always able to just restart the program from where it last left off, I would ideally like to be able to leave it running till it finishes its course.

Does anyone have any idea about the possible cause/fix for this?

Thank you.

run.xml:53 ->

```html
<java classpath="${classpath-translated}" classname="${classname}" dir="${work.dir}" jvm="${platform.java}" fork="true" failonerror="${java.failonerror}">
```